# Mac App Store: How auto update happens for an Application which requires installer

Tags: mac, mac-appstore

We've an application which we are planning to add to App Store.

Till now we were hosting an installer on Enterprise Servers and users were downloading it from server.

Does App store support such applications which requires multiple components to be installed using an installer?

We need installer as it installs the main application and start backend service.
Also, how auto update will happen if new version of application is available on AppStore, will it start package installer?

Please provide pointers on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Mac App Store Review Guidelines - Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/mac/#functionality):

> **2.14** Apps must be packaged and submitted using Apple's packaging technologies included in Xcode - no third party installers allowed
>
> **2.15** Apps must be self-contained, single application installation bundles, and cannot install code or resources in shared locations
>
> **2.16** Apps that download or install additional code or resources to add functionality or change their primary purpose will be rejected

Comment: Please clarify for me, according to [the App Distribution Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/SubmittingYourApp/SubmittingYourApp.html), a Mac Installer Package can be created and submitted.  So does this installer need to be only a single App? or can it be something like a preference pane or server?